# ParametricPlot3D step size

Tags: plotting, packages

I tried to use ParametricPlot3D which appears in the kernel, such as;

```
ParametricPlot3D[{xALL, yALL, zALL}, {ξ, 0, 5}, {η, 0, 3}];
```

but here parameter's step size is default and I want to determine this step size explicitly.

I searched and learned of a package `` Graphics`ParametricPlot3D` `` which provides the user to determine the step size explicitly.

The problem is; where could I download this specific package and then which folder will I put this package and thirdly; how to call this package in the notebook cell. Lastly; Im using Mathematica v.9 and is the package compatible with v.9 ?

Comment: It does *adaptive* plotting by default, so you can't really speak about "step size". That old package you speak of was for the older times when that function was not yet fully built-in, and did not have adaptivity.

Comment: Of course you can generate a `ListPlot[]` which has a predefined step size. 
`ListPlot[Table[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 0, 2 \[Pi], 1}], Joined -> True]
ParametricPlot[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` provide the same basic plot.
If you're looking to increase the quality of a regular plot, use `MaxRecursion->`

Comment: @Feyre Thank you for your answer but I want to plot 3D therefore I try to use ParametricPlot3D and Im sure there must be a way to add the step size and found the package Graphics ParametricPlot3D but dont know how to download and add this package.

Comment: It's not really compatible with the current version of *Mathematica*. But, why do you need to specify a step size? If you need smoother curves, just adjust the settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`, as noted in the docs.